# Projecting a point onto a hypercube

Tags: projective-geometry, projection

Let's consider a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a hypercube $H_n = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n: a_i \le y_i \le b_i \}$, where $a_i < b_i, i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ are fixed, real numbers.

I would like to find a way to project $x$ on $H_n$. How can it be done and why that way is correct? How can I check whether a projection truly is a projection?

By projection I mean "to the nearest point".

Comment: Does "project onto" mean "find the nearest point"? If not, what does it mean? What if the point is inside? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Typically we project onto subspaces, which the hypercube isn't. Do you want the closest point on H to x?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the point $y$ inside the hypercube that is closest to a given point $x$ like this:

$y_i=\begin{cases}x_i<a_i:&a_i\\a_i≤x_i≤b_i:&x_i\\x_i>b_i:&b_i\end{cases}$

- If $x_i$ is less than $a_i$, the "projected point" should be on the surface of the hypercube with the smallest coordinate ($a_i$);
- If $x_i$ is between $a_i$ and $b_i$ that coordinate should go unchanged: it's already within the parameters for that coordinate;
- If $x_i$ is more than $b_i$, the "projected point" should be on the surface of the hypercube with the greatest coordinate ($b_i$).